# VNC Server: cannot log in from desktop when logged from VNC user

Tags: vnc, alma-linux

I have setup VNC server on my laptop. When I log into the laptop via VNC, I cannot log into my laptop from the desktop GUI. The problem is if I close my VNC session and forget to log out from VNC, I cannot log in the laptop from the desktop GUI.

I would like either one of the following to happen:

1. If already logged in and you log again as the same user from another location, the session will be shared.
2. If already logged in, forcefully disconnect the previous session and connect as that same user from where ever you connected.

Here's the instructions I have followed: https://www.webconn.tech/kb/how-to-configure-vnc-server-in-almalinux-8-3 to setup VNC.